# Incremental sum in Oracle SQL using analytic functions

Tags: sum

How can I sum values per record from a table?
If I have

| row | key | value | expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| row 2 | A | 5 | 6 |
| row 3 | B | 10 | 10 |
| row 4 | B | 1 | 11 |
| row 5 | B | 1 | 12 |

can you point me some directions?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Windowing Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-2877E1A5-9F11-47F1-A5ED-D7D5C7DED90A)

Something like

```
select t.*, 
sum(value) over (partition by key order by "row" rows unbounded preceding) expected
from tab t;
```

Note that `ROW` is a reserved word. You can create a table with a column `row`, but you better use another name.